# Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUser"

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I use cloudformation template from other AWS account but today I have this error:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUser" (RequestToken: d55c7a26-473f-3eda-b1af-fdc97afc5364, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

My cloudformation template:

```
  CGNAdminUser:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUser
    Properties:
      DesiredDeliveryMediums:
        - EMAIL
      UserAttributes:
        - Name: email
          Value: !Ref Email
      Username: !Ref Username 
      UserPoolId: !Ref CGNUserPool
```

I try add this but do not work:

```
DependsOn: CGNUserPool
```

I try change `UserPoolId: !Ref CGNUserPool UserPoolId` by `UserPoolId: !GetAtt CGNUserPool.UserPoolId` but do not work again

**May be AWS bug today because, my user is created !!**

[image]

Comment: You might try looking at CloudTrail logs to see if there is a specific API call that is failing. But you may need to submit a support request for this one so someone can take a closer look. If CloudFormation is giving you an error message, but the user gets created anyway, then I agree this might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it must be `UserPoolId: !GetAtt CGNUserPool.UserPoolId`

Comment: I write I try change UserPoolId: !Ref CGNUserPool UserPoolId by UserPoolId: !GetAtt CGNUserPool.UserPoolId but do not work again